# Page reload on hash change with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm nearly there with my code,
highligting div based on selected clicked a with hash id.

The only problem left is the page is not reloading on click

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var idh = window.location.hash

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a"+idh).parents("div:first").addClass("uthevet");

     $(".Nytt-over a").click(function() {
       var newLoc = this.attr('id');
       window.location.hash = newLoc;
       location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
```

I see the hashtag changing on click, but no reload.
What do I do wrong?

Page
http://relasjonsledelse.no/Nytt/Nyheter.asp#BiGO
(Click on one of the headings in the body, this should change the highlighted area)

Comment: did you try `window.location.reload()` ? Check your browser console.

Comment: @ivy_lynx the script scope is `window` anyway, so it's not required

Comment: There are errors in your code, check the error console (F12).

Comment: "TypeError: undefined is not a function" in console when I click the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to wrap `this` in a jQuery object in the click handler. It was failing on the call to `attr`:

```
$(".Nytt-over a").click(function() {
       var newLoc = $(this).attr('id');
       window.location.hash = newLoc;
       location.reload();
    });
```

Or use `var newLoc = this.id;` as Joe suggests :)

When in doubt, use the F12 debugger consoles provide by Chrome, IE etc.

Comment: Also can just do `this.id`, jQuery isn't needed here

Comment: "*When in jQuery... be needlessly inefficient*"? :P jQuery is a tool for making things easier, but I don't think `$(this).attr('id')` is easier than `this.id` ;-)

Comment: @Joe: Adding more code might then require `var $this = $(this);` followed by multiple uses of `$this`. I like to code one way to allow for maintenance. As for efficiency, can you click 50,000 times a second (which is when it would matter)? :)

Comment: It doesn't matter for performance, it's just much easier to mentally parse `this.id`, because there's no syntactic sugar. Also `$(this)` is incredibly fast to run (I believe it's the joint-fastest possible selector with `$(document)` etc) so in many ways, `$this = $(this)` is actually not really much of an optimisation at all :-)

Comment: @Joe: Ah, if you want to argue *mental parsing*, that is a personal preference. I did not come to jQuery via a Javascript+DOM route, so tend to always do it the jQuery way first (unless efficiency does become an issue, which it hasn't after 2 years jQuery). I so accept that this is your opinion and do not wish you to change at all :)

Comment: Thank you all!
I expect this is very basic jQuery.
Working excellent now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below code

```
var newLoc = $(this).attr('id');
```

instead of

```
var newLoc = this.attr('id');
```

Surely it will work. When you give 'this' it doesn't call the jQuery function to get attribute id. And one more thing is no need to specify the the window object and again call reload, simply set like

```
location.hash = 'your link';
```